# Unavailable names ("name") are used for form controls

Tags: html, forms, webforms, contacts, contact-form-7

Okay so, This error is keep on popping up and I don't understand why am I getting this error at all? I know there are some reserved words for contactform-7 but hey I changed everything to your now what?

```
<div id="form" method="post" your-name="send">
    <!-- col start -->
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        [text* name id:your-name class:requiredField class:your-name placeholder "Your Name"]
    </div>
    <!-- col end -->
    <!-- col start -->
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        [email* email id:your-email class:requiredField class:your-email placeholder "Email"]
    </div>
    <!-- col end -->
    <!-- col start -->
    <div class="make-space">
        [text* subject id:your-subject class:requiredField class:your-subject placeholder "Subject"]
    </div>
    <!-- col end -->
    <!-- col start -->
    <div class="make-space">
        [textarea* message class:requiredField class:your-message placeholder "Message"]
    </div>
    <!-- col end -->
    <div>
        <!-- button start -->
        <div class="more-wraper more-wraper-form">
            <div class="more-button">
                [submit class:more-button-wrapper "Submit"]
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- button end -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Unavailable names ("name") are used for form controls. Please help me out will ya?

Comment: The answer is in the error message... `[text* your-name id:your-name class:requiredField class:your-name placeholder "Your Name"]`

Comment: Is this really a webforms question? Check the description.